# Send data from java to php using sockets - always NULL

Tags: java, php, sockets, ports

I try to communicate between php and java unsing sockets. Both running on the same machine. Sending data from php to java works pretty well. But the other way around doesn't.

I tried a lot of other examples as well therefor I'm not even sure if the problem occurs because of the code or any other thinks happening around.

- Firewall is set off
- Incomming and outgoing port roles for Port 4308 are set to allow connection.
- Browser: Chrome and Firefox
- Server uniServer using Apache

The very simple example I'm using now:

Java (sender):

```
public static void testSend() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        Socket socket = null;
        OutputStreamWriter osw;
        String str = "Hello World\n";
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 4308);

        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        osw.write(str, 0, str.length());
        osw.flush();

        socket.close();
}
```

I'm not sure if the osw.flush() is necessary (I tried with and without).

php (receiver):

```
<?php
    echo "start\n";

    $address = 'localhost';
    $port = 4308;

    $mysock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_bind($mysock,$address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');
    socket_listen($mysock, 5);
    $client = socket_accept($mysock);

    // read 1024 bytes from client
    $input = socket_read($client, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);

    var_dump($inpit);

    socket_close($client);
    socket_close($mysock);

    echo "end";
?>
```

Answer from the php code:

```
start NULL end
```

When I monitor the Port on TCPView I can see, that the php script is listening on this port, when I then start the java program, its stops listening and returns NULL. That means the php script noticed the connection but didn't get the "Hello World\n" String.

Comment: You mentioned Chrome/Firefox and Apache, but this is Java -> PHP via TCP sockets. Where does the browser or Apache come into it? They work over HTTP. And what exactly goes wrong? The response is null? Any errors on the PHP side?

Comment: TBH if you want to talk to a PHP script over the network (the fact they're on the same physical machine doesn't really make a difference to the way the connection process happens), would it not actually be easier to use HTTP?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Apache is the server where the php runs on and chrome and firefox was the browser where I tested it, I was not sure if it can help, therefor I added it to my question.

Comment: I didn't get any error messages.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Apache responds to HTTP requests, not raw TCP socket requests. But then your code seems to try and listen to a socket on another port (Apache normally listens on 80 unless you specifically configured it differently). And you can't run Java in a browser, or at least not without a plugin. Exactly what process did you use to run both sides of this?

Comment: Where does `$inpit` gets assigned?

Comment: @ADyson, in the end I need to communicate between js and java. Java is running on the same machine as apache (but not in apache or in a broser or something like that, just on the same machine) and is doing (complex) route computations. My plan is that the js (which builds the googlemaps page) calls the php file with two locations then the java program computates the path and returns them as a json back to php and then the js get the json from the php page. Therefor the php page is kind of an API. I'm not sure if it is the best solution.

Comment: @ Usagi Miyamoto that was the problem it should be $input like in the upper line. I was reading the code the whole day again and again looking for the mistake, but didn't find this simple misstake. shame on me. Thank you a lot.

Comment: so if java gets some data from PHP, and then sends it a result back, why does Java need to initiate a socket connection with PHP? Surely it's the other way round? Also, it's possible to write server-side Java using JSP, which might integrate better with your Java background process. Another way, if the Java program can be run as a one-off, is to initiate a command-line session from PHP to execute the Java program with the given input, and either capture the response from stdout, or have Java write the results to a file or database which PHP can read

Comment: Just seen the above. Ok so it basically works, but I'd say probably there is a smoother way to architect it. How is the java program knowing to begin the socket connection? Presumably something earlier in the PHP is telling it to start processing, based on some input from the browser?

Comment: Is a communication over the command-line or over files better than using sockets? I'm new to this topic, after reading a bit I thougt sockets would be the best solution. Do I not need browser plugins for using JSP? That example above was a simplimfication just to find the mistake why it was possible to send data to the java but not to get it back. Your right, in the end php has to initiate the socket.

Comment: JSP runs on the server and generates HTML just like PHP does, so you don't need any browser plugins for it. It's probably a matter of debate whether sockets are better or not. If the Java program is always running in the background, sockets would seem to be a way to do it, but if the Java is run as a one-off program each time, then you could do it a different way. Equally if the Java code that does the calcs is part of a library that you could include in a JSP program, that would save you all the integration work.